# Adjusting Android H.264 Codec and running it on a phone

Tags: android, android-ndk, h.264, codec, openmax

First of all I should let you know that I am new to Android system.

I would like to slightly adjust the existing H.264/AVC Codec that Android uses. Specifically I would like to change the way codec calculates whatever data it gets from an input buffer, before sending it to an output buffer.

As I took a look at Android Media Architecture it seems that [stagefright](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libstagefright/codecs) is  only some kind of wrapper and I cannot find source code for OMX IL Hardware H.264 Implementation.

So my first question I guess is, where does computing from bits into actual picture happens?

The second part of the problem is getting this adjusted codec into mobile device. I guess I just rewrite the existing file (when I find it)? As far as I understand I do not need to follow [Implementing custom codecs](https://source.android.com/devices/media#codecs) as I would like to keep changed codec registered with the same name.

At this point I should tell you that I am not hoping this will work in general use but only in custom app for research purpose.

Edit 1: I am not expecting an answer with the exact solution, but would appreciate some guidelines, to where to start off my exploration with the goal of modifing codec.

Edit 2: I will be using unsecured (rooted) device.

Comment: This is far too broad a question to fit here, but it is probable that you cannot readily modify the codec unless you are building a custom version of the Android operating system to install on an unsecured device.  Otherwise, you almost certainly have to treat your codec as a custom add-on under a new name and brought along with the app that uses it, even if you derive it from AOSP source.  Note that your custom codec link points to AOSP documentation (ie, customizing Android), and not developer documentation for those writing apps to install on existing devices.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I am aware that the question is very broad and I am not expecting answers telling me what exactly to do. Better, I would appreciate some guidelines. My plan indeed is to use unsecured device. Will edit the question.